# Outbound Mail not working

Tags: php, email, drupal, civicrm

I am using Civicrm for my drupal web site . Here i want to send email by going through the option administer -> system setting -> OutBound email .
There i have selected the mail() option and by clicking on **Save & Send Test Email** its showing success about the sending of the email as

> Mail Sent
>   Sending test email. FROM: source@hostname.com TO: destination@gmail.com
>   Your MAIL settings are correct. A test email has been sent to your email address.

But I am not able to get the email in my indox . i have gone through the docs of [civicrm](http://book.civicrm.org/user/current/advanced-configuration/email-system-configuration/)

Thanks

Comment: The mail will be sent to `destination@gmail.com`. make sure you have this id as logged in your inbox

Answer (score 0):

Three things you can check :

1) Make sure you don't have mail log (CIVICRM_MAIL_LOG) enabled in your `civicrm.settings.php`.

2) Create a mail account at `Administer -> CiviMail -> Mail Accounts`.

3) Try executing the Scheduled job for `Scheduled Mailing` in `Administer -> System Settings -> Scheduled Jobs`